# Django: stop resubmit duplicate data when many time press Enter Key in keyboard

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I created a form for data submission. When a user successfully fillup that form, I am using **HTTP redirect** method. Now Everything is okay and data do not resubmit when user want to page refresh.
But user fillup that form and press *Enter key* again and again. Same data added how much user press *Enter key* button. I want to stop that. A user can be press *Enter key* onetime. Data do not add in the database if a user will press Enter Keyboard second or more time.

**this is my form html file**

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}

{% block content_area %}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <p>Customers Details</p>
        <hr>

        <div class="customers_info_due">
            <p>Invoice ID: : {{due_customers.customer_uid}}</p>
            <p>Name: {{due_customers.customer_name}}</p>
            <p>Product Name: {{due_customers.customer_product_name}}</p>
            <p>Price: {{due_customers.customer_price}} TK</p>
            <p style="color:red">Customer Paid First Time: {{due_customers.customer_first_time_payment}} Taka</p>

            {% if track_invoice %}
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>SL</th>
                        <th>Paid Taka</th>
                        <th>Paid Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for x  in track_invoice %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.customer_due}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.customer_due_date}}</td>

                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <tr>
                        <td> Total</td>
                        <td><b>{{sum_cost_taka}}</b> TK </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            {% else %}
            {% endif %}

            <p>WARRENTY: {{due_customers.customer_product_warrenty}}</p>
            <p>QN: {{due_customers.customer_product_quantity}}</p>
            <p>Mobile No: {{due_customers.customer_mobile_no}}</p>

            <p>Sell Date: {{due_customers.customer_sell_date}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <p>Update customers due info</p>
        <hr>
        <div class="due_forms">
            <form action="{% url "shop:dueupdate" due_customers.id %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Add this customer name: {{due_customers.customer_name}}</label>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="due_taka_add">Due taka add:</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="due_taka_add" placeholder="Enter amount" name="due_taka_add" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="customer_due_info">Write Due Info:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer_due_info" placeholder="Write due info" name="customer_due_info">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content_area %}
```

**this is my views.py**

```
def dueupdate(request, customer_id):
    sys_type='updatedue'

    due_customers = get_object_or_404(CustomerInfo, pk=customer_id)
    track_invoice = due_customers.duetaka_set.all()

    if request.method =='POST':
        due_taka = request.POST['due_taka_add']

        due_info_update_add = request.POST['customer_due_info']


        due_customers.duetaka_set.create(customer_due_info=due_info_update_add, customer_due=due_taka, customer_due_date=timezone.now())

        track_invoice=due_customers.duetaka_set.all()



        sum_cost_taka = track_invoice.aggregate(
            sp=Sum('customer_due')).get('sp', 0)


        if sum_cost_taka == None:
            sum_cost_taka=0

        total_paid_taka = sum_cost_taka + due_customers.customer_first_time_payment

        CustomerInfo.objects.filter(id=customer_id).update(
            customer_due_taka_info=total_paid_taka)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('shop:customersProfile', args=(due_customers.id, sys_type,)))
```

Also, I used unique keyword within Model Class, but I cant solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to at least start using a form for this all and don't use your "raw" POST data.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm

Such that the view reduces to:

```
def dueupdate(request, customer_id):
    sys_type='updatedue'

    due_customers = get_object_or_404(CustomerInfo, pk=customer_id)
    track_invoice = due_customers.duetaka_set.all()

    form = CustomerInfoForm(request.POST or None, instance=due_customers)
    if form.is_valid():
        due_customers = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('shop:customersProfile', args=(due_customers.id, sys_type,)))
```

Put all the logic you've built into this form and do the update of the data in the `save` method of that form.

Comment: So I have to use Django forms.